# Matrix representation as projected unitary encoding

Tags: matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. In many places i see that $A$ can be represented as a *projected unitary encoding*, i.e. the matrix can be written as $A=PU\tilde{P}$, where $P,\tilde{P}$ are orthogonal projectors, and $U$ is a unitary matrix.

Why is this the case? I never saw such decomposition in any course of linear algebra. In fact, it is not any of the LU,QR,SVD, eigenvalue,Cholesky decomposition that I can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) on wikipedia.

What is the algorithm to come up with the decomposition?

Comment: Start from SVD and consider $V=V^\frac{1}{2}UV^\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You mean the SVD of A? V for you is the orthogonal matrix of the SVD of A=U\SigmaV^T? Thanks.